# Bash (Ubuntu) - Strings in while loops?

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to create a while loop in bash that won't continue until the user enters the word "next".  I can't seem to figure out how to use strings for the condition though.

```
#Beginning of code
echo -e "Please type next to continue."
read word 
while [ "$word" -ne "next" ]
do 
    read word
done
#the rest of the code
```

Comment: when you compare strings you should use = or ==. So your while loop should look like: `while [ "$word" = "next" ]` The -eq is used for numeric comparision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have stated you should not use the `-ne` integer comparison to compare strings - rather you should use `=/!=` in `test` `[` brackets `]`. Still though, even that is brittle at best - the strings must match exactly, and `''` *does* equal `''`. It is often better to handle `case`s in that context:

```
set --
while   read  word
        case $?$#$word            in 
        ($?$#[Nn][Ee][Xx][Tt]) ! :;;
        ([!0]*|05*) ! break       ;;esac
do      set '' "$@"
done
```

Provided a default value for `$IFS` *(which is worth looking into if you plan to do shell `read`s)*, that should work for any upper/lower value of `next` *(if you require it)* and keep the loop from running away without end.

Comment: Hmmm... Now I'm wondering why I thought it should have been easier the other way. But I think it was because I considered that an EOF should not return true in the same way 5 consecutive failures should not return true.

Answer (score 17):

Use `!=` instead of `-ne`

```
echo -e "Please type next to continue."
read word 
while [ "$word" != "next" ]
do 
    read word
done
```

Check this for comparison operators. 
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-11.html

Answer (score 4):

I think you want:

```
echo 'Please type "next" to continue.'
while read word && [ "$word" != next ]; do
  : something in the loop if needed
done
```

It's a good idea to also check for end-of-file on stdin (here by checking the exit status of `read`).

Comment: I had `read ... && case` at first, but it seemed easier just to set a low limit because a runaway tty read loop would be more annoying than 5 reads. Still - it was lazy. I suppose I could do `$?.$#$word` now that I think about it...

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong comparison operator. You should use "!=" for string and "-ne" for integers as follows:

```
#Beginning of code
echo -e "Please type next to continue."
read word
while [ "$word" != "next" ]
do
    read word
done
#the rest of the code
```

Checkout this page: [Advanced `bash` Scripting: Comparison Operations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)